# Searching for words in richTextBox (windows forms, c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, richtextbox, string-matching

I need help with counting same words in richTextBox and also want to assign numbers/words to them. There are 500,000 + words in a box and all of them are written only 3 or 6 times. 
One solution is to write down words i'm looking for in advance, search in a box and assign a number/word to it. But there are too many to do so, if there is a quicker way it will help me a lot.
Thanks in advance!

Here is a code of what i'm doing right now, it's not representing what i'm asking.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Url.Length; i++)
        {
            doc = web.Load(Url[i]);

            int x=0;
            int y=0;

            //here was a long list of whiles for *fors* down there, 
            //removed to be cleaner for you to see 
            //one example:                 
            //while (i == 0)
            //{
            //    x = 18;
            //    y = 19;
            //    break;
            //}

            for (int w = 0; w < x; w++)
            {
                string metascore = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"trow8\"]")[w].InnerText;
                richTextBox1.AppendText("-----------");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(metascore);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
            {
                string metascore1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"trow2\"]")[z].InnerText;
                richTextBox1.AppendText("-----------");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(metascore1);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with searching a RichTextBox. This also doesn't sound like a very good idea - why are you using a textbox? It seems like an in-memory list or dictionary would work better for this.

Comment: I just wanted to show what i'm doing right now. What do you mean by in-memory list or dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have your text, read from a file, downloaded from some webpage, or RTB... Using LINQ will give you all you need.

```
string textToCount = "...";
// second step, split text by delimiters of your own
List<string> words = textToCount.Split(' ', ',', '!', '?', '.', ';', '\r', '\n') // split by whatever characters
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))                           // eliminate all whitespaces
            .Select(w => w.ToLower())                                            // transform to lower for easier comparison/count
            .ToList();
// use LINQ helper method to group words and project them into dictionary
// with word as a key and value as total number of word appearances
// this is the actual magic. With this in place, it's easy to get statistics.
var groupedWords = words.GroupBy(w => w)
   .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());`

// to get various statistics
// total different words - count your dictionary entries
groupedWords.Count();
// the most often word - looking for the word having the max number in the list of values
groupedWords.First(kvp => kvp.Value == groupedWords.Values.Max()).Key
// mentioned this many times
groupedWords.Values.Max()
// similar for min, just replace call to Max() with call to Min()
// print out your dictionary to see for every word how often it's metnioned
foreach (var wordStats in groupedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{wordStats.Key} - {wordStats.Value}");
}
```

This solution is similar to previous post. The main difference is that this solution is using grouping by word, which is simple and putting it to dictionary. Once there, a lot can be easily found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a RichTextBox running around somewhere, we will call him Bob:

```
        //Grab all the text from the RTF
        TextRange BobRange = new TextRange(
                // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
                Bob.Document.ContentStart,
                // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
                Bob.Document.ContentEnd
            );

        //Assume words are sperated by space, commas or periods, split on that and thorw the words in a List
        List<string> BobsWords = BobRange.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();

        //Now use Linq for .net to grab what you want
        int CountOfTheWordThe = BobsWords.Where(w => w == "The").Count();

        //Now that we have the list of words we can create a MetaDictionary
        Dictionary<string, int> BobsWordsAndCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach( string word in BobsWords)
        {
            if (!BobsWordsAndCounts.Keys.Contains(word))
                BobsWordsAndCounts.Add( word, BobsWords.Where(w => w == word).Count(); )
        }
```

Is that what you meant by assign a number to a word?  You want to know the count of each word in the RichTextBox?

Perhaps add a bit of context?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the count of each word in richTextBox and to write that number before that word. For example, this will be the sentence from that box after the edit: "(4)Comments (1)are (45)used (34)to..."
Numbers represent how many times was that exact word used. Next time there will be "Comment" in any sentence, it should have (5) before itself.
I get what you wrote here and how I can count exact words, but can't figure out how to make that in general.

Comment: Check my post. Just replace Console.WriteLine($"{wordStats.Key} - {wordStats.Value}"); in the foreach loop with Console.WriteLine($"({wordStats.Value}){wordStats.Key}"); and you'll get exactly what you need.

Comment: @NickWhite is the RTB going to be constantly updating, and therefore your counts will be changing?  So the count will be of all previous words?  ie: "(1)Count (2)count, (3)count (4)count"

Comment: I want to implement that function after the *for loop* ends, so every time I start my soft, it will write down all words in RTB and after it's done, it should count every single one in it.